# How to loop through input type number in vuejs so that I can track value of each iteration?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

In my opinion, it's a simple question but couldn't make it work after many efforts.
I have an array named as `mainList`, on every iteration of array, I render input element:

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 resource-list" v-for="resource in mainList" :key="resource">
       <span>{{ resource }}</span>
       <div class="quantity-box">
           <input
                    type="number"
                    step="1"
                    min="1"
                    :id="resource"
                    :name="resource"
                    v-model="initialValue"
             />
       </div>
</div>
```

where `initialValue=0`. The Problem I am facing is, whenever I try to change value of one input box, all gets changed. I want to add all the input field having value greater than `initialValue` to an array and perform some task with that array. How can I do so ? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**:  When I replace  `v-model="initialValue"` with `:value="initialValue"`, one input selection doesn't change the value of others but don't know how to save them on an array.
This is my `data.js` file code which I have imported.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      initialValue: 0,
      mainList: [
        "Analytices & insights",
        "Journey Mangment",
        "Segments & Audience",
        "Personalised experiences",
        "Campaign Orchestration",
        "Customer Acquisition"
     ]
   }
 }
}
```

Right now this is how it looks:
[image]

**Expected Output**: I want to save those resource name into an array whose value is greater than 0.

Comment: please share whole code snippet and sample input and expected output

Comment: The question is edited. You can have a look. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by `v-model="initialValue"`. You are effectively mapping *every input field to the same variable*.

Changing one input changes the variable and effectively every other input field. One solution would be to omit `v-model`'s two way binding and instead just listen to `change` on the input element and call a custom method which sets the appropriate value on `initialValue`. You could keep the inputs and their values in a dictionary / object `{$inputname : $value}`.

Say you want to display the total amount you could use a computed property for that which iterates over the values of your dictionary and sums them up.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qoha4w36/) which gets you to your desired result.

Comment: Hi Thomas. I have one doubt, how can I loop through inputs and just print the name of the resource as right now when I loop, it prints just the number corresponding to that resource.

Comment: I got it. `resource` became the index and the `number` become value.

Answer (score 1):

Simply to have a `values` object to bind every input to it's properties:

Here is a working example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-shape-z7w90?file=/App.vue)

```
<template>
 <div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 resource-list" v-for="(resource, index) in mainList" 
     :key="resource">
  <span>{{ resource }}</span>
  <span style="font-size:0">{{values[index] = initialValue}}</span>
  <div class="quantity-box">
     <input
           type="number"
           step="1"
           min="1"
           :id="resource"
           :name="resource"
           v-model="values[index]"
    />
  </div>


</div>
   <br>
   <input  id="button" type="button" value="add greater nums" 
     @click="addGreaterNums()">  

 </div>

 </template>

 <style>
    body { padding: 1rem; }
  </style>

  <script>
   export default {
   data() {
    return {
      mainList: [
      "Analytices & insights",
      "Journey Mangment",
      "Segments & Audience",
      "Personalised experiences",
      "Campaign Orchestration",
      "Customer Acquisition"
      ],
      initialValue: 1,
      values:{}
    }
   }, 
  methods: {

     addGreaterNums: function(){
       for(var key in this.values){
         // get all inputs value greater than initialValue
         if(this.values[key] > this.initialValue){
          console.log(this.values[key]);
        }
      }

     }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your data is something like this,

```
data() {
    return {
      mainList:[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],
      initialValue: 0,
    };
  }
```

the problem with your code is you use `v-model` with initialValue which now comman state for each itarations.

To fix this, remove `initialValue: 0` from current file and just create separate vue file for input field with that state data then render it 'n' times so you can have it's own state rather than sharing a same state for each input.